# An identity about primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$p_1,\dots ,p_s$ are all given primes, prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{i_1,\dots ,i_s\geq 0}\frac{1}{p_1^{i_1}\cdots p_s^{i_s}}=(1-\frac{1}{p_1})^{-1}\cdots (1-\frac{1}{p_s})^{-1}$$

Comment: Aren't these equal?  For $s=1$, say, it's just the usual sum of a geometric series.  No?

Comment: @lulu You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{s}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^{s}\left(1+\frac{1}{p_k}+\frac{1}{p_k^2}+\ldots\right) = \sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_s\geq 0}\frac{1}{p_1^{s_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{s_k}}.$$